# vscode intellisense import not working within jest ts tests

Tags: import, visual-studio-code, jestjs, javascript-intellisense

all throughout my project, VSCode will automatically prompt to import a type (the yellow lightbulb appearing). Except within JEST test files (within my **tests** directory), I get no lightbulb. I can manually write the import, at which point any further imports within the same file are detected.

does anyone know how to fix this?

regards, Tilli

Comment: Are your tests part of a `jsconfig` or `tsconfig` project? Try running the `JavaScript: Go to project configuration` vscode command in one of your test files to check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vscode TS language features unavailable when tests/\*\* are not included in the tsconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943069/vscode-ts-language-features-unavailable-when-tests-are-not-included-in-the-ts)

Answer (score 7):

I was experiencing the same issue, Matt Bierner's response got me to the correct solution.

#### The Problem

I had this project layout:

```
./lib/
./src/
./tests/
./tsconfig.json
```

In my tsconfig I had:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

It was the tests being excluded, i.e. `"**/*.spec.ts"`, which was preventing vscode from suggesting imports inside the tests.

Obviously, when this was removed, when build ran, the tests would end up in my `./lib` output dir.

I discovered a better solution to remedy both problems.

### The Solution

I split the `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```
./lib/
./src/
./src/tsconfig.json
./tests/
./tsconfig.base.json
./tsconfig.json
./package.json
```

The `./tsconfig.base.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

The `./tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json"
}
```

The `./src/tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../lib"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

The build script was modified so that it would use the `./src/tsconfig.json` file, which required the `-p ./src/` part to be added, as per the example below.

The `./package.json` file:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
      ...
      "build": "tsc -p ./src/"
      ...
    }
  ...
}
```

I hope this helps anyone that has the same issue.

Comment: this helped me, but there has got to be a better way, I come across this problem a lot and can't seem to find any real mention of this. how are people dealing with it is beyond me

Answer (score 2):

For my case adding the following to `tsconfig.json` fixed the problem.

```
{
  ...
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

What is strange is that I didn't have this in my configuration from the beginning of the project, suddenly the import intellisense stopped from working, and had to add the above option to config file.
I hope this helps.