# Vscode TS language features unavailable when tests/** are not included in the tsconfig

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, ts-jest

I would like my typescript tests to receive linting, code completion, vscode intellisense (ts language features) when the `test` folder is adjacent to the `src`. I do NOT want the tests to transpile when I build my typescript project.

My typescript node project is structured like this:

```
.    
├── server
│   │ 
│   │    
│   ├── src
│   │   │
│   │   └── app.ts
│   ├── test
│   │   │
│   │   └── app.test.ts
│   ├── node_modules/
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── tslint.json
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── front_end/
└── README.md
```

With my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

When I navigate to my test files in vscode, the vscode language feature wont recognize types and packages installed in node_modules. SURPRISINGLY, if I open vscode only in the server folder (as you can see from my folder structure server is not the root), the language features work .

The tests use `ts-jest` to run so the `tsc` is not needed here. Would it be better practice to extend a `tsconfig.json` for tests ?

Is this something that can be fixed in the settings or should I submit a bug to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vscode has a problem with a one root tsconfig file. An adjacent `test` folder to `src` will use the tsconfig (added in this [pull request](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/tsdx/commit/157bceefaae9cd36549a6b9f4562fe502ec2186b)) however it won't work if the folder you open is one directory above it (for example if you have a server & client folder). A solution is being tracked in this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12463.

In addition, if you want to upgrade to eslint (tslint is deprecated), the typescript parser will also force you to add a tsconfig file to the test folder if you wish to keep the test folder excluded in the main tsconfig. [Link to eslint multi tsconfig docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/MONOREPO.md#one-root-tsconfigjson).

The easy solution is to use two extra `tsconfig`s. One for the linter `tsconfig.eslint.json` and one for tests **inside** the `test` folder: `test/tsconfig.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"]
}
```

Not elegant but a better solution does not exist at this moment.

Comment: Can you please explain in more details what should be in `tsconfig.tests.json` and how should it be related to the main `tsconfig.json` in your answer?

Comment: @AKd Actually what I did is in the `/test` folder (that is adjacent to the `/src` folder) I called the file `tsconfig.json` and this is what it looks like: https://gist.github.com/Shahaed/9661cf6320e7bb60de828138ef35a856

That seems to work. In the root (one level up from this) there is a tsconfig.json and tsconfig.eslint.json

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I have instinctively come to the same solution. However I had to include the source folder (`"include": [".", "../src"]`) in the `test/tsconfig.json` file to make auto import work in VSCode: http://prntscr.com/vkmytx.

Comment: @akd interesting, I get auto imports to work and I didn't need that. It's all a black box to me at this point.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you so much for this!

Comment: @Shahaed i have an additional issue of getting error  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70069829/cannot-use-import-outside-of-module-typescript-test-directory

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my computer to test this but I think you just need to add the following code to your ts json file.

```
"exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.test.ts"
    ]
```

Break down: Exlude ** all folders / * all ts files with .test in them.

if you're not using node then you can omit the node_modules part. But I want it in my answer in case someone who is using node copies the exclude. Defaultly node_modules is excluded but adding more modifiers can over write that.

good luck.

Hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Exclude is not needed here since the tsc will NOT compile the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extend your tsconfig so that you have a common one, a production one and a development one. In our case, we have this:

tsconfig.common.json - contains all the settings shared by development and production.

tsconfig.json - the development version that includes tests:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.common",
    "exclude": ["bin", "node_modules"]
}
```

tsconfig.prod.json - the production version that excludes the tests.

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.common",
    "exclude": ["bin", "node_modules", "tests", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Then with our webpack.config, we have a similar setup:

webpack.common.js - contains all the settings shared by development and production

webpack.dev.js - use the development tsconfig:

```
rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: [/bin/, /node_modules/],
            include: /ClientApp/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                configFile: 'tsconfig.json'
            }
        }
    ]
```

webpack.prod.js - uses the production tsconfig:

```
rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: [/bin/, /node_modules/],
            include: /ClientApp/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
                appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                configFile: 'tsconfig.prod.json'
            }
        }
    ]
```

And lastly, the package.json file has the following in the scripts section:

```
scripts: {
    "dev": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: While a good solution (I've done this in the past), a tsconfig for a folder that won't be ever be compiled seems not needed. Since our test runner is ts-jest, our tests should just need linter coverage.